# PDFBox: PDJpeg gets drawn in wrong colors when resized -> Adobe Reader -> Windows XP & 7

Tags: java, swing, pdf, bufferedimage, pdfbox

When creating a PDF using PDFBox and drawing PDJpegs to it, the images' colors are changed / inverted when resizing the PDJpeg(s) before drawing them to the PDF. This issue is only visible on Windows XP and Windows 7 using e.g. Adobe Reader. Preview on Mac or the new PDF preview build in Windows 8 are somehow not affected by this.

**Samples:**

[Screenshot PDF in Adobe Reader](http://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12575058/Screen%20Shot%20Windows%20XP%20Adobe%20Reader.png) 
[Same PDF in Mac Preview](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12575057/Screen%20Shot%20Mac%20OSX%20Preview.png)

**This is what I do in code:**

- Create PDDocument
- Create HashMap of PDJpegs (for caching purpose):

  - Create PDJpegs by BufferedImage initialised through ImageIO.read()
  - Resize PDJpegs by calling setHeight() and setWidth() on PDJpegs
  - Adding PDJpeg to HashMap
- Create PDPage and add it to PDDocument
- Create PDPageContentStream
- Draw some PDJpegs on the PDPage
- Close PDPageContentStream
- Save PDDocument
- Close PDDocument

Method for resizing the PDJpegs:

```
private void preparePDFIconCache(List<AbstractDataItem> list) throws IOException {

    iconCache = new HashMap<String, PDJpeg>();

    for (AbstractDataItem item : list) {
        String iconResourcePath = "/com/graphics/icons/" + item.getIconName();
        URL iconURL = this.getClass().getResource(iconResourcePath);

        BufferedImage icon = null;
        if (iconURL != null) {

            icon = ImageIO.read(iconURL);

        } else {

            String myIconResourcePath = SettingsDataModel.getInstance().getMyIconsPath() + File.separator + item.getIconName();

            File iconFile = new File(myIconResourcePath);
            if (iconFile.exists()) {

                URL myIconURL = iconFile.toURI().toURL();

                if (myIconURL != null) {

                    icon = ImageIO.read(myIconURL);
                }
            }

        }
        if (icon != null) {

            PDJpeg pdfIcon = new PDJpeg(currentDocument, icon);

            pdfIcon.setHeight(iconWidthXHeight);
            pdfIcon.setWidth(iconWidthXHeight);

            iconCache.put(item.getIconName(), pdfIcon);
        }
    }
}
```

If the BufferedImages are resized before initialising the PDJpegs, everything works fine, but they don't look that sharp.

Does anyone have a good solution or experienced the same issue?

Comment: It may be helpful if you include some actual code snippets, particularly the code for resizing the image.

Comment: Just added some code to my question.

Comment: let me guess .. Are you using CMYK jpeg images?

Comment: Thanks for your question. No, I'm using RGB PNG images with an alpha channel: [image info](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27442615/image%20info.png)

Comment: As image files I tried both: PNGs (with alpha channel) and JPEGs (without alpha channel). Both images don't look like the original in the PDF opened with Adobe Reader, when resized.

Comment: It would be useful to forward these RGB PNG images with an alpha channel to the development team, please open an issue in PDFBox JIRA or e-mail me the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing the image with PDPageContentStream#drawXObject and setting width in height in this method resolved the issue.

Comment: Please add some code, so we can understand How you solved it!!